# redmine or ruby 500 internal error when creating new project: undefined local variable

Tags: ruby, redmine

I just installed redmine on ubunutu/nginx/postgres and I get this error when creating a new project... any ideas? (I'm new to ruby so can't really tell what it wants to happen)

```
Started GET "/projects/new" for 50.116.19.7 at Tue Aug 14 08:31:52 +0200 2012
Processing by ProjectsController#new as HTML
  Rendered projects/_form.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered projects/new.html.erb within layouts/base (6.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 131ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `self_and_descendants' for #<Project:0xb490ca54>):
    4: <!--[form:project]-->
    5: <p><%= f.text_field :name, :required => true, :size => 60 %></p>
    6: 
    7: <% unless @project.allowed_parents.compact.empty? %>
    8:     <p><%= label(:project, :parent_id, l(:field_parent)) %><%= parent_project_select_tag(@project) %></p>
    9: <% end %>
    10: 
  app/models/project.rb:333:in 'allowed_parents'
  app/views/projects/_form.html.erb:7:in
'_app_views_projects__form_html_erb___577557764__627958918'
  app/views/projects/new.html.erb:4:in     '_app_views_projects_new_html_erb___126828522__630632748'
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:950:in `labelled_form_for'
  app/views/projects/new.html.erb:3:in     '_app_views_projects_new_html_erb___126828522__630632748'
```

**from redmine/app/models/project.rb  (sorry, cant seem to figure out how to propery format code to display here**)

```
# Returns an array of projects the project can be moved to
   # by the current user
  def allowed_parents
    return @allowed_parents if @allowed_parents
    @allowed_parents = Project.find(:all, :conditions =>        Project.allowed_to_condition(User.current, :add_subprojects))
    @allowed_parents = @allowed_parents - self_and_descendants
    if User.current.allowed_to?(:add_project, nil, :global => true) || (!new_record? && parent.nil?)
  @allowed_parents << nil
end
unless parent.nil? || @allowed_parents.empty? || @allowed_parents.include?(parent)
  @allowed_parents << parent
end
@allowed_parents
  end

  # Sets the parent of the project with authorization check
  def set_allowed_parent!(p)
    unless p.nil? || p.is_a?(Project)
      if p.to_s.blank?
        p = nil
      else
        p = Project.find_by_id(p)
     return false unless p
  end
end
if p.nil?
  if !new_record? && allowed_parents.empty?
    return false
  end
elsif !allowed_parents.include?(p)
  return false
                                                                                            334,5         35%
elsif !allowed_parents.include?(p)
  return false
end
set_parent!(p)
  end
```

Comment: The error is in Project Model `app/models/project.rb:333:in 'allowed_parents'`
 can you please paste your Project model here?

Comment: thanks!!! ill paste the snippet in above as here is not so many characters allowed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function call self_and_descendants as you have declared in your Project model.

Use self.descendants

Check out this link [Class descendants](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/descendants)

Comment: aha... hm, well i just commented out that line, and i get to the page i can create projects, but again an error when saving a new project.
    #@allowed_parents = @allowed_parents - self_and_descendants

Comment: What line you commented the one on the view file or one in the model where you are getting the error. As you are saying you are still getting the error then you must have commented the view file line. The error is not in your view its in model.

Comment: in project.rb:333 
it did something, i was able to see the page to create a new project, then a new error when saving the new project:
NameError (undefined local variable or method `store_new_parent' for #<Project:0xb4b667c8>):
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:79:in `create' ---


makes me think the proper route is not commenting things out. strange though, this is a fresh install of redmine.

Comment: Could you please put your controller code, view code and your model code completely

Comment: which files would those be? sorry, i dont know, i looked for controllers, got many many in the controllers dir.
by model code you mean  models/project.rb?
and a certain view file?

Comment: maybe related...
there are no icons for the quick insert code.. screenshot > (http://i1082.photobucket.com/albums/j364/peterthimaging/Screenshot2012-08-15at125542PM.jpg)

Comment: still havnt figured this out :( would really be grateful for any help here from someone that knows the system better! :)